# How to write Django templates tags {% %} in HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I do not know how to fix this...

[template tags image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2tgf.png)

```
def generate_some_svg_data():
    return '{% block content %}<svg width="100" height="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /> </svg>{% endblock %}'

def my_view(request):
    svg_data = generate_some_svg_data()
    return HttpResponse(svg_data)
```

Comment: from the image it seems like everything is working perfectly, what is your question?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not use a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell django that svg_data is a Django template to interpret the tags:

```
from django.template import RequestContext, Template

def generate_some_svg_data():
    return '{% block content %}<svg width="100" height="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /> </svg>{% endblock %}'

def my_view(request):
    svg_data = generate_some_svg_data()
    template = Template(svg_data)
    return HttpResponse(template)
```

in case you have a context too you can do as follow:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = RequestContext(request, {"a":1, "b":2})
    svg_data = generate_some_svg_data()
    template = Template(svg_data)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```